# asp.net mvc publish multilayer web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a sln and 4 layer
domain.Core(class lib)
domain.Data(class lib)
domain.Admin(asp.net mvc 4) 
and domain.Web(asp.net mvc 4)

domain.core incule referans add data
domain.admin ve domain.web iclude referans data and core is okey.

domain.Web is publish and upload server.
but domain.com/Admin is not found

Why? Thanks for help

Comment: Because you published only domain.Web and "its" dependencies. domain.Admin is not a dependency for domain.Web

Comment: I understand but how to use admin project for domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the problem.

First approach is to publish domain.Admin as `Admin` in IIS.

[image]

Second approach is to make Admin as ***Area*** inside domain.Web. If you use Area, you do not have to publish them individually. In addition, you can share data between domin.Web and Admin. You can look at my sample project at GitHub - [Areas/Administration](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/tree/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web).